# Why does my D3 legend color ramp replace my second legends colors when I remove it in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, legend

I am creating a React application and have a component that creates D3 legends for every layer I have selected. When I have multiple legends showing and one gets deselected, the remaining legend has its color ramp replaced by the colors of the removed legend. I would expect my remaining legend to have its proper color ramp.

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import * as d3 from "d3";

function formatColors(colors, numberStops) {
    let colorOffsets = [];
    colors.forEach((colorHex, index) => {
      const colorPct = ((index / numberStops) * 100.0).toFixed(2);
      colorOffsets.push(
        {offset: `${colorPct}%`, color: colorHex}
      );
    });
  return colorOffsets;
}

const D3Legend = (props) => {

  const d3Container = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(props.serviceType && d3Container.current){
      const numberStops = props.legendStyle[props.serviceType].colors.length - 1;
      const colors = props.legendStyle[props.serviceType].colors;
      const colorOffsets = formatColors(colors, numberStops);
      
      const svg = d3.select(d3Container.current);
      
      const defUpdate = svg.selectAll("defs").data([1]);
      const defEnter = defUpdate.enter().append("defs");
      defEnter.append("linearGradient");

      const linearGradient = defUpdate.merge(defEnter);
      linearGradient
        .select("linearGradient")
        .attr("id", `linear-gradient-${props.serviceType}`)
        .selectAll("stop")
        .data(colorOffsets)
        .enter().append("stop")
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });

       defUpdate.exit().remove();

      const update = svg.selectAll("g").data([1]);

      const enter = update.enter().append("g");
      enter.append("rect");

      const bar = update.merge(enter);

      bar
        .select("rect")
        .attr("width", 220)
        .attr("height", 15)
        .style("fill", `url(#linear-gradient-${props.serviceType})`);

      update.exit().remove();
    }
    }
  },
  //React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'd3Container.current'.
  //Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 
  //'d3Container.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them 
  //doesn't re-render the component  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  //[props.serviceType, d3Container.current])
  [props.serviceType])

  return (
    <>
      <svg
        className={"d3-legend " + props.legendStyle[props.serviceType].type}
        ref={d3Container}
      />
      <span className="d3-x-axis">Low</span>
      <span className="d3-x-axis">Med</span>
      <span className="d3-x-axis">High</span>
           
    </>
  );
}

D3Legend.propTypes = {
  serviceType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  legendStyle: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default D3Legend;
```

Below is the html elements when both legends are toggled (left) and when deselecting the top one (right).
[image]

The `stop-color`s from the deselected layer / legend end up replacing the ones for the still active layer / legend even though the correct legend name and ID is present.

I think it is related to how D3 binds the data and selects elements but I can not seem to work it out.

### Update

Adding `svg.selectAll("*").remove();`
below `const svg = d3.select(d3Container.current);`
Has seemingly stopped this issue from happening. I don't quite understand why though...